# How to open eww in readable mode?

Tags: eww

I have added in my init something like:

```el
(defun today-CA ()
  (interactive)
  (eww "https://www.google.com"))
```

This opens `eww` through the `today-CA` function. I want to open it in readabe form, i.e. as if `eww-readable` had been invoked in the `eww` buffer. How to do that? This doesn't work:

```el
(defun today-CA ()
  (interactive)
  (eww "https://www.google.com")
  (eww-readable))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This doesn't work

The reason calling `eww-readable` right after `eww` does not work is because `eww` is asynchronous; when `eww-readable` is called the `eww` buffer is not yet rendered, so there are no "unreadable" parts to omit.

> How to do that?

There may be a more elegant way, but if you have [lexical binding](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LexicalBinding) (see the last section) enabled in your init file, you can write something like the following:

```el
(defun today-ca ()
  "Open Google homepage in `eww' with `eww-readable' enabled."
  (interactive)
  (letrec ((nonce (lambda ()
                    (unwind-protect
                        (eww-readable)
                      (remove-hook 'eww-after-render-hook nonce)))))
    (add-hook 'eww-after-render-hook nonce))
  (eww "https://google.com"))
```

The basic idea is adding the function `eww-readable` to `eww-after-render-hook`, so that it is run in the finalised buffer. The only issue lies in cleaning up the [hook](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html) so that `eww-readable` does not apply all the time.

We can't call `remove-hook` right after `eww` because `eww-after-render-hook` will not have been run by that point. So the function we add to `eww-after-render-hook` must remove itself. With `lexical-binding` we can just create a [closure](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Closures.html) as per my previous example. Alternatively, you could write an additional global helper function:

```el
(defun my-eww-readable-nonce ()
  "Once-off call to `eww-readable' after EWW is done rendering."
  (unwind-protect
      (eww-readable)
    (remove-hook 'eww-after-render-hook #'my-eww-readable-nonce)))

(defun today-ca ()
  "Open Google homepage in `eww' with `eww-readable' enabled."
  (interactive)
  (add-hook 'eww-after-render-hook #'my-eww-readable-nonce)
  (eww "https://google.com"))
```

You could remove the call to `unwind-protect`, but it ensures the hook is cleaned up even if something in `eww-readable` fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can also load the content manually with url-retrieve and render it in eww yourself, and then run eww-readable, like this

```
(defun t/eww-readable-after-render (status url buffer)
  (eww-render status url nil buffer)
  (switch-to-buffer buffer)
  (eww-readable))

(defun t/eww-readable (url)
  (interactive "sEnter URL: ")
  (let ((buffer (get-buffer-create "*eww*")))
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (autoload 'eww-setup-buffer "eww")
      (eww-setup-buffer)
      (url-retrieve url 't/eww-readable-after-render (list url buffer)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Basil's answer, here is a solution for using [eww](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/EWW.html) to browse dash API docs - effectively making [dash API docs](https://melpa.org/#/dash) open in eww buffers that are then collapsed to "readable" form.  eww-readable-url can also prompt for a URL to open in eww-readable form if you pass nil and can be called interactively from anywhere to open a eww-readable browser.

```elisp
     (use-package
       eww     
       :custom
       (browse-url-browser-function 'eww-browse-url) 
       (dash-docs-browser-func 'eww-readable-url)
       :config
       (use-package helm-eww)
       (defun make-eww-readable()
         ;; make current eww buffer eww-readable and then remove the hook that called this so normal buffers are not eww-readable.
         (unwind-protect
             (eww-readable)
           (remove-hook 'eww-after-render-hook #'make-eww-readable)))

       (defun eww-readable-url (url)
         ;; when the eww buffer has rendered call a hook function that implements eww-readable and then removes that hook.
         ;; primarily for 'dash-docs-browser-func
         (interactive "sURL:")
         (add-hook 'eww-after-render-hook #'make-eww-readable)
         (eww url))
       :bind 
       ("C-c o" . 'browse-url)
       ("C-c O" . 'eww-readable-url)
       (:map eww-mode-map
             ("O" . www-open-current-page-external) 
             ("o" . www-open-link-external)))
```